# Python Selenium check if new element becomes available

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a bot that checks when there are new houses on the website so that i can use selenium's click events.

How can i keep track of this list and check when there are new houses added to the website? I have created a list filled with  elements of the available houses, but don't know how to go further on from here..

Thanks for the help!

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    service = Service(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, chrome_options=options)
    
    return driver

def login(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'txtEmail').send_keys('XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com') 
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'txtWachtwoord').send_keys('XXXXXXX')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept"]'))).click()
    #driver.find_element(By.ID, 'CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-secondary').click()
        
def search_page(driver):    
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='/zoekopdracht/']").click()
    

    
def list_of_woningen(driver):
    woningen = []
    woningLijst = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"stretched-link")

    for x in woningLijst:
        woningen.append(x.text)

    return woningen


    
        
    
def start_session(driver,url):    
    driver.get(url)
    login(driver)
    search_page(driver)
    list_of_woningen(driver)
    
    

    #return driver.page_source
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_session(create_driver(),'https://hurenbij.vesteda.com/')
```

Comment: do you have a local list of houses? or is that every time you open the website, the program collects the current houses and the data will be gone when the program is closed?

Comment: No , not a local list.. It is a list created of the current houses. Data will be gone when program closes.. @Hannonqaoud

Comment: run loop which every few seconds loads page again, scrapes all data again and compares data with your list.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if a there's an event lister that you can deploy or anything similar, but you can do it the manual way, you can re check if anychanges has occurred every 30 seconds or so.

```
def check_for_changes(driver, old_list):
    print("Checking for changes")
    new_list = list_of_woningen(driver)
    if old_list == new_list:
        print("No changes found")
        return False
    else:
        print("Changes found")
        print("Old list: ", old_list)
        print("New list: ", new_list)
        return True
    
def start_session(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    login(driver)
    search_page(driver)
    old_list = list_of_woningen(driver)
    while not check_for_changes(driver,old_list):
        sleep(30) # 30 seconds
        # a better approach for this, is to make a wait thread, if there are other functionalities for tha program 
        driver.refresh()
    else:
        print("ALERT!!!")
```

once again there might be a better solution with a built in selenium event listener, but this is a valid solution.